# Mallet topic modelling, labelling topics

Tags: java, topic-modeling, mallet

I have a corpus of articles in a single document and I am applying the topic modelling algorithm from MALLET in order to later use a search function that will allow the user to search for relevant articles to his input. The algorithm I'm using is the topic modelling API developers guide found [here.](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics-devel.php)

I am new to topic modelling, but as far as I understand it generates a user-specified number of topics that hold words relevant to this topic, but the program does not know what the topic is. This has to be specified manually by the user, am I right?

My question is, how do I manually set these topic names so I can use them later?
i.e. a topic output from the algorithm will be:

```
0 bush republican usa immigration mexico control conservatives
```

where 0 is the name of the topic. What I want is to manually change the name to something like:

```
Immigration Policy: bush republican usa immigration mexico control conservatives
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you keep a separate file with topic number and manually assigned labels, e.g., in the format

```
0 Immigration_Policy
```

Then you can relate the topic numbers in all output files from Mallet to the labels.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a separate file"? How would you implement that programmatically?

Comment: @deadpixels You have to assign the labels manually, So I suggest just write a separate file with topic numbers and labels with your favourite text editor.

Comment: good approach of having a mapping variable that maps topic number to its variable.